# Quadratic Complex roots solver

Tags: vb.net

Cannot seem to make the console print out the complex roots correctly.

```
If quad4ac < 0 Then

        Dim quad4acComplex As Long = quad4ac * -1
        Dim quadiComplex As Long = -1
        Dim quadrComplex As Long

        Console.WriteLine(vbNewLine & "Your Roots Are Complexed!" & vbNewLine)

        quadrComplex = (-quadCoB / (2 * quadCoA) & "+" & (quad4ac * -1) ^ 0.5 / (2 * quadCoA))
        Console.WriteLine(quadrComplex)
```

Seems to be causing the console to crash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to assign a string value to a long value and then print the long value. I don't really know what you are trying to do. In case you want to print out the calculated value try:

```
quadrComplex = CType((-quadCoB / (2 * quadCoA) + (quad4ac * -1) ^ 0.5 / (2 * quadCoA)), Long)
Console.Writeline(quadrComplex.Tostring)
```

In case you want to print out the expression try

```
Dim quadrComplex as String
quadrComplex = "(-" & quadCoB.Tostring & " / (2 * " & quadCoA.ToString & ") + (" & quad4ac.ToString & " * -1) ^ 0.5 / (2 * " & quadCoA.ToString & "))"
Console.Writeline(quadrComplex)
```

You should consider enabling `Option Strict` in your program. That way you are forced by the compiler to use the correct type conversions yourself. This avoids many many errors.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with ampersands `&` here?

> ....(2 * quadCoA) **&** "+" **&** (quad4ac * -1)...

Problem is that `&` is a string concatenation in VB.NET, which of course cannot be assigned to a `Long`.

What do you expect console to print at this line?

```
Console.WriteLine(quadrComplex)
```

The answer for you will be somewhere between these two questions.